# Check if 1st timepicker earlier than 2nd timepicker

Tags: java, android

I have 2  timepicker which represent start and finish. It means the start time must be earlier than the finish.

My idea is to use `Calendar` class and use `getTimeInMillis` to do the validation, but its not working :

```
            Calendar calFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calTo = Calendar.getInstance();

            calFrom.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeSchedule.getCurrentHour());
            calFrom.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeSchedule.getCurrentMinute());
            calTo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, toTime.getCurrentHour());
            calTo.set(Calendar.MINUTE, toTime.getCurrentMinute());

            if(calFrom.getTimeInMillis() > calTo.getTimeInMillis())
            {
                Crouton.makeText(MyActivity.this, "error", Style.ALERT).show();
            }
```

When i debug the above code, although the `timeSchedule` is earlier then `toTime`, the value of `calFrom.getTimeInMillis()` is bigger than  `calTo.getTimeInMillis()`.

Please kindly help me, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
int fromHour = calFrom.getCurrentHour();
int toHour = calTo.getCurrentHour();
int fromMin = calFrom.getCurrentMinute();
int toMin= calTo.getCurrentMinute();

if (fromHour >toHour )
{
        System.out.println ("from time is greater");
}
else if (fromHour==toHour)
{
     if (fromMin>toMin)
     {
          System.out.println ("from time is greater");
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println ("To time is greater");
      }
}
else
{
     System.out.println ("To time is greater");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your solution shortly. But why time in millis not working? I think using millis will make my code simpler

Comment: @BlazeTama  I also tried using millis but don't know why it is not working. Hope anyone will come with good answer and description.

Comment: @BlazeTama Now your orignal question code working fine. Why this is hapening? Before some time it is not giving expected result. is there is any GMT like issue.

Comment: Do you mean my code is working? Its not working in my case..i use default android datepicker